# Extract date from date time and used result as condition in the same awk script

Tags: awk, group-by

Here is the input data save as input.csv

```
aNumber|bNumber|startDate|timeZone|duration|currencyType|cost|dicatedAccused|balanceAfter|trafficCase|teleServiceCode|location|dataVolume|numberOfEvents|fafIndicator|netWorkID|serviceProvideID|serviceClass|nAno|nBno|bNumberZnCode|fileNamedID|Destination|Operator|unknown3|MainAmount|ReAnalyse|DEDICATEDACCBALBEF|DEDICATEDACCBALAFT|ACCOUNTGROUPID|SERVICEOFFERINGS|SELECTEDCOMMUNITYID|BALANCEBEFORE
22677512549|778|2014-07-02 10:16:35.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|0.00|NULL|11.50|0|4|22676020076|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|34|77512549|778|NULL|1131257|OTHER|Short Code|126244088|0.0000|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|11.5000
22675557361|76457227|2014-07-02 10:16:38.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|10.00|NULL|1009.10|0|4|22676613028|NULL|NULL|1|NULL|NULL|35|75557361|76457227|NULL|1131257|Airtel|Airtel|4132206314|10.0000|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|1019.1000
22677521277|778|2014-07-02 10:16:42.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|0.00|NULL|0.00|0|4|22676020078|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|34|77521277|778|NULL|1131257|OTHER|Short Code|130071591|0.0000|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|0.0000
22676099496|77250331|2014-07-02 10:16:42.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|1.00|9|0.50|0|4|22676613028|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|35|76099496|77250331|NULL|1131257|Airtel|Airtel|4132218551|0.0000|0|4.0000|3.0000|NULL|NULL|NULL|0.5000
22667222160|22667262389|2014-07-02 10:16:43.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|10.00|NULL|16070.00|0|4|22676613028|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|35|67222160|67262389|NULL|1131257|Airtel|Airtel|4132222628|10.0000|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|16080.0000
22665799922|70110055|2014-07-02 10:16:45.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|20.00|6|0.50|0|4|22676020076|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|35|65799922|70110055|NULL|1131257|Telmob|Telmob|126260244|20.0000|0|44.0000|24.0000|NULL|NULL|NULL|0.5000
22676239633|433|2014-07-02 10:16:48.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|0.00|NULL|0.20|0|4|22676020027|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|35|76239633|433|NULL|1131257|Airtel_TollFree|Short Code|397224944|0.0000|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|0.2000
```

I have to group by `date`,`dicatedAccused`,`trafficCase` and `teleserviceCode` and then based on the result of this group by I have to sum up `duration`, `cost`, `balanceAfter`, `MainAmount` and `Balancebefore`. I used a awk script as follow:

Here is the awk script I'm using (saved as `test.awk`):

```
BEGIN {FS=";"}NR == 1 {next}{key=sprintf("%10s %10s %12s %12s",$3,$8,$10,$11)   duration[key] += $5 cost[key] += $7 bAfter[key] += $9 main[key] += $26 dedAccbBefore[key] += $27 dedAccbAfter[key] += $28 bBefore[key] += $NF}END {
printf "%-10s\t\t %10s %12s %12s %10s %10s %10s %10s %12s %12s %10s\n", "date","dAccused","TrafficCase","ServiceCode","Duration","Cost","BalanceAfter","MainAmount","DAcBlBefore","DAcBlAfter","BalanceBefore" 
for (i in duration) { 
    printf "%-47s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s\t %10s\n", i,duration[i],cost[i],bAfter[i],main[i],dedAccbBefore[i],dedAccbAfter[i],bBefore[i] }}
```

When I run my awk script:

```
$ awk -f test.awk input.csv
```

The output I have is:

```
date                       dAccused  TrafficCase  ServiceCode   Duration       Cost BalanceAfter MainAmount  DAcBlBefore   DAcBlAfter BalanceBefore
2014-07-02 10:16:45.000          6            0            4          0         20        0.5         20          0         44          0.5
2014-07-02 10:16:42.000       NULL            0            4          0          0          0          0          0          0            0
2014-07-02 10:16:38.000       NULL            0            4          0         10     1009.1         10          0          0       1019.1
2014-07-02 10:16:42.000          9            0            4          0          1        0.5          0          0          4          0.5
2014-07-02 10:16:35.000       NULL            0            4          0          0       11.5          0          0          0         11.5
2014-07-02 10:16:43.000       NULL            0            4          0         10      16070         10          0          0        16080
2014-07-02 10:16:48.000       NULL            0            4          0          0        0.2          0          0          0          0.2
```

My concern is that I want the date only to be displayed, not along with the time because it is ruining my all script.
I expect the output to be:

```
date       dAccused TrafficCase ServiceCode Duration    Cost    BalanceAfter    MainAmount  DAcBlBefore DAcBlAfter  BalanceBefore   
2014-07-02   6       0           4           0           20      0.5             20             0            44          0.5    
2014-07-02  NULL     0           4           0           10      17090,8         20             0            0          17110,8 
2014-07-02   9       0           4           0            1      0,5             0              0            4           0,5
```

Any idea will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. change `FS=";"` into `FS="|"`
2. change `..}{key=sprintf("...` into `..}{sub(/ .*/,"",$3);key=sprintf(...` that is, add the `sub(/ .*/,"",$3);`

the date should be in required format.